# How to simulate Touch event in Linux/Mac/Windows?

Tags: linux, macos, events, touch, multi-touch

I wanna to simulate touch event in Windows / Mac OS X or Linux (OS is not critical).

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows Vista and Windows 7, the [Multi-Touch Vista drivers](http://www.codeplex.com/MultiTouchVista) let you use 2 mice to simulate multi-touch gestures.  It should degrade nicely to the "normal" touch experience.  In my experience, it can be fairly tricky, but it works.

It really kind of depends on what you're working on and what the goal is.  If you can separate the response from the action in your application, that will make it a lot easier to test something like this without going through a lot of hassle.

If you wind up needing a touch device, [Wikipedia has a nice list of multi-touch devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Multi-Touch_Computers_and_Monitors).

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time passed since this question, however, maybe someone will google for similar question and find that there is another option:

If you have android device, you can use your device as touch screen for windows.
Maybe there are other software to do this, but I used following one:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tnksoft.winmultitouchfree

This program from some japanese guy coupled with desktop app does the trick.
You can get desktop app from his site http://www.tnksoft.com/ .
Unluckily it is japanese site, but it's not hard to find necessary program there(it has easily recognisible icon)>
Alternatively you can get link once you install android app.